# How do I open a terminal in the current location?

Tags: nautilus

I've recently switched from Kubuntu to Ubuntu and while I like the speed and cleanlyness, I'm missing some power features, particularly in Nautilus, like:

- Opening a terminal in the current location

Are there extension for Nautilus to add these kinds of features? Or maybe a different file manager altogether. I know I can still use Dolphin but that doesn't integrate very well.

Comment: I've split off your second question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17969/how-do-i-type-a-path-or-url-directly-into-nautilus

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Installing `nautilus-open-terminal` (from the Software Center or using `apt-get`) adds the option to open a terminal in the current directory to the right click menu:

[image]

Comment: This nautilus opens the terminal one step back from the current location? Is this a bug or what is the issue?