# How do I type a path or URL directly into Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

How can I type a in a path or URL (ftp, sftp, etc.) directly into Nautilus instead of having to browse around?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> allows you to type in a path:

**Screenshots**:

*Ubuntu 11.04 and below*:
[image: Nautilus 2.3x]

*Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04*:
[image: Nautilus 3 Screenshot]

To change this permanently see here: [Typing location path instead of clicking directory buttons in the file picker dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13645/typing-location-path-instead-of-clicking-directory-buttons-in-the-file-picker-dia)

Comment: Will it work with http URL? I couldn't make it work e.g. while pointing to http image URL as an attachment for Evernote note.

Comment: This is an example of hidden UI. Why hide basic, core functionality that's been common to file browsers forever behind a keyboard shortcut that everyone will regularly forget?

Answer (score 16):

Another tricky is just to press <kbd>/</kbd> Then you can type path with automcomplete options when double <kbd>tab</kbd> click.

It will lead you to write the absolute path which means starting from /.

[image]

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> give you the path of your current location and you can from change your path.

[image]

Comment: Still works with latest Gnome in 2020! I used to be able to doubleclick that area, but no more. `/` and `ctrl + L` both work in Gnome 3+!