# How can I copy the current path from Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

In 10.10, when opening a directory in Nautilus, I was wondering how to copy the current path?

My address bar, pictured here, is not copyable:

[image]

Comment: I suppose that you want to `cd` to the directory Nautilus is in. A quick way to do that would be to `right-click` and select `open in terminal` (as long as your `~/.bashrc` doesn't set your `pwd`)

Comment: OP doesn't want to open a terminal there but wants to copy the current location to the clipboard which as the accepted answer shows is really easy.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I'd say the quickest way is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, then you can copy it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: is it a feature or a bug? :-)

Comment: I don't really think it's a bug.... that's how it has been designed (wether we like it or not)

Comment: Hehe it's a feature for sure and I believe it has been implemented for the same reason this question has been asked :P

Comment: It used to show the location bar all the time, now breadcrumb style navigation is the default. Oh and +1 for keyboard shortcuts!

Comment: And to toggle it back, strangely, you can't use Ctrl+L. You have to use Esc. (See my answer for other related tips about saving your preference for this, and about "terminal here".)

Comment: `Ctrl+c` on the file/directory and `Ctrl+v` in an editor. If you find this useful, vote on the [answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1093983/157360) (not me!)

Answer (score 30):

`Ctrl+L`. Very frustrating to not find an option in the View menu (which should then be clearly labeled Ctrl+L). Had to do a web search.

And then very frustrating to find that Ctrl+L doesn't toggle it back. Another web search... Drum roll... `Esc`

And then, how to set your preference? Web search... Have to install gconf-editor or dconf-editor or manually use a terminal command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true
```

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1504058

Of course, this would be a little less painful if there were a 'terminal here' option in the context menu. Web search... Install `nautilus-open-terminal`

[How do I open a terminal in the current location?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17961/how-do-i-open-a-terminal-in-the-current-location?rq=1)

Sigh. Oversimplified interfaces are so hard to figure out. I appreciate all the helpful answers people have put on the web for us to find.

Comment: This answer will work on Ubuntu >12.04. Gconftool (answer below) is deprecated.

Comment: Worth restating!
"Oversimplified interfaces are so hard to figure out."

Answer (score 7):

May I ask why you want the path?

If you want the path because you want to use it and navigate directly from the terminal, then you can simply install **nautilus-open-terminal** using **synaptic**.

Or

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

After that, simply right click on any folder and use "Open in terminal"

If you simply want the path, then Ctrl + L would do just fine.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package nautilus-open-terminal`.

Comment: The path is useful for making notes, writing user documentation, answering questions about "Where is file X located" and so on.

Answer (score 6):

Copy the file or folder. When you paste on terminal or text editor, it will paste the path, not the file or folder.

Comment: Drag from Nautilus and drop into Terminal works too!

Answer (score 5):

## You can use a [Nautilus script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto):

Paste

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "${PWD}" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

into `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Copy Directory Path`.

(requires that [xclip](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xclip) is installed)

You can now right-click on a file, mouse over "Scripts", and choose "Copy Directory Path" to copy the path of the directory that contains the file. <sub>Caveat: will not work in an empty directory.</sub>

### Explanation

- `echo -n "${PWD}"`: Echoes the current working directory (Nautilus sets the working directory of the script to the one you had open in the window from which you ran the script) without a trailing newline. Initially I considered `pwd | head -c -1`, since pwd includes a trailing newline, but that was two unnecessary calls to external programs compared to `echo`.
- `xclip -selection clipboard`: `xclip` by default copies to the X11 "primary" clipboard, but most desktop environments use the "clipboard" clipboard for their clipboard. <sub>I can't believe I just wrote that</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to the GO menu and choose Location....

Answer (score 1):

You can also type into your terminal `gconftool-2 --type=Boolean --set apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_location_entry true` so that you always get a text based location bar.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the answer of Nonny Moose, you can **create, and use a Shortcut for copy to the clipboard the Path to your file/folder**. Thus, you select a folder or a file in Nautilus, and then press a shortcut, and you will have you Path to that folder/file in the Clipboard ready to be pasted.

You can do in the following manner:

1. Install Xclip: $ sudo apt install xclip
2. Create and save a script in ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts as follow:

   - Name of the file: Nautilus-Copy-Path
   - Content:

     ```
     #!/bin/sh
     echo -n "${PWD}" | xclip -selection clipboard
     ```
   - Make this file an executable file. (Risght click -> properties -> permissions -> Alow executing file as program)
3. Create the following file in /home/user_name/.config/nautilus

   - Name of the file: scripts-accels
   - Content: Note that `F6` is the shortcut you want to assign to run this script, space and then the name of the script you want to run, in this case the file name you just have created in the previous step.

     ```
     F6 Nautilus-Copy-Path
     ```
   - Make it executable
4. Restart Nautilus

Comment: In Nautilus versions later than the one that comes with 20.04, a simple Ctrl+C again will work as of old. Note that this also will not work like that on Wayland, the default display server of Ubuntu 22.04.