# Get location of "true" GVFS path from Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, 12.10, gvfs

I mount my Samba shares through Nautilus. I know that, behind the scenes, the share is fuse-mounted and Nautilus somehow does the translation between `smb://` URLs and the actual location in the file system.

Is it possible to retrieve the "true" path in the file system for a GVFS-mounted share, for a directory or a file? How?

**EDIT**: If anything else fails, one could invent a tool that is applicable to any file and would just copy the command-line parameter to the clipboard. Then it would just be required to tell Nautilus to offer this tool for all files and directories.

This is related, but does not answer my question: [How can I copy the current path from Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28511/how-to-copy-the-current-path-from-nautilus)

Comment: Related, but doesn't help either: http://askubuntu.com/q/23413/30266

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with "Nautilus Actions":

http://www.howtogeek.com/116807/how-to-easily-add-custom-right-click-options-to-ubuntus-file-manager/

The general idea is as follows:

1. Install `nautilus-actions`.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
   ```
2. Create the following script in any directory in your `PATH`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   TEXT=$1
   shift

   echo -n "$TEXT" | xclip $@
   ```
3. In `nautilus-actions`, create a custom action that calls this script with parameter `"%f"`. You may need to restart Nautilus.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot find an easy way of getting `nautilus` to tell you this. However, there are other ways of finding out.

In Ubuntu 12.10, the "actual path" is under `/run/user/USERNAME/gvfs`. In 12.04, I think it was under `/home/USERNAME/.gvfs` (invisible unless you check `View->Show Hidden Files` in `nautilus`). The folder names inside these directories look something like `smb-share:server=servername.local,share=volume_1`.

Comment: Thank you, I know the location. I was just looking for a shortcut. +1 for the useful information, anyway.

Comment: Right, but whenever you navigate there it shows the masked location again.