# where i can find nas share drive nautilus mounted in terminal

Tags: command-line, nas, smb

Exactly like the title, I managed to open smb nas share from nautilus and bookmark it  or map it for future access.

Now i'd like to access it using terminal. I tried to find it under /mnt or /media but no luck. Any body knows where it mounted?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/213581/get-location-of-true-gvfs-path-from-nautilus

Comment: Great!!! so it laid under .gvfs (hidden) folder under our home folder. With this I can woof any file or folder from nautilus smb-mounted to just pointed it to .gvfs folder from terminal $woof .gvfs\share_folder\file_name. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing gvfs from command shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/232497/accessing-gvfs-from-command-shell)