# How to access gvfs mounts from command line?

Tags: command-line, 12.10, gvfs

I have some samba share mounted via Nautilus and I'd like to access the files from command line. They used to appear under `$HOME/.gvfs` but not any more.

Where have they gone to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 12.10, gvfs mounts can be found in `/run/user/<uid>/gvfs`.

Where `/run/user/<uid>` is the value of env `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`

Comment: Note: you can get the <uid> by the command id -u and by using  the backticks you can get the output in another commandline, like this: "ls -al /run/user/`id -u`/gvfs "

Comment: backticks are alas interpreted as markup elements, google it to find out how to use them, there are a lot of good forum examples.

Answer (score 4):

As Eric's answer says, it also applies to 14.04:

It is in `/run/user/<uid>/gvfs` instead of `/run/user/<username/login>/gvfs`.

Please note that:

`<uid>` is user id = number

while

`<username/login>` is a string, human readable user name

Where one to the other is mapped through /etc/passwd or any other nss module (e.g. ldap). The numbers is actually stored on disk while the name is just for humans :-)