# How to mention a folder in a network?

Tags: networking, gvfs, calibre

I'm a returning user to Ubuntu, I've used it several years ago and now I'm getting back.

I use calibre do manage my e-books collection, and I have a desktop running win7 and my notebook running Ubuntu. All my library is on my desktop, how can I make my Ubuntu's Calibre access my library on my desktop?

**Note**: I can access my library normaly via file explorer.

When I had windows on this notebook, I needed only to tell calibre that the way is:

```
\\GUSTAVU-PC\bibliotecado
```

I don't know what's the equivalent to this on Ubuntu, when I hovered the mouse over the mentioned folder on the file explorer, it gave me a link:

```
smb://gustavu-pc/bibliotecado/
```

But when I tried to input this on Calibre, it understood it as:

```
/home/g/smb://gustavu-pc/bibliotecado
```

I don't know how to tell it that this location is on the network.

Comment: Maybe calibre doesn't support `smb` protocol.

Comment: I guess it does, I just used the file path provided by the answerer of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/232497/how-to-access-gvfs-mounts-from-command-line).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have accessed the shared drive, Ubuntu typically creates a link to it under ~/.gvfs/ - probably named "bibliotecado on gustavu-pc".

Have a look in that directory (it's hidden, so you'll be best using a terminal - type `ls ~/.gvfs/`. Then you can tell Calibre to look in that directory.

Comment: I got this: `ls: cannot access /home/g/.gvfs/: No such file or directory`

Comment: I guess I got it, I've made calibre access the folder described by [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/232497/how-to-access-gvfs-mounts-from-command-line), once inside the folder I could access the shared directory.