# How open folders from USB devices in Terminal and find the size

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

I am very new in Ubuntu. I just plugged my mobile in Ubuntu and the two memory cards appears to me. But I was interested to find out the total free space and how much used for each folder. I guess that I have to use df + something.

Comment: try `lsblk` command.

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't use `df`, you'll use `du`, which is a tool that displays disk usage.

You first need to find out where your mobile phone has been mounted. If you're using Ubuntu 12.10 or later, [it'll most likely be mounted under `/run/user/<login>/gvfs`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232497/how-to-access-gvfs-mounts-from-command-line) on a folder called `mtp:host=<someNumbers>`.

Here is how mine looks like right now:

```
aa@aa-ul:~$ ls /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host\=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/ -l
total 0
drwx------ 1 aa aa 0 Jan  1  1970 Internal storage
drwx------ 1 aa aa 0 Jan  1  1970 SD card
```

So if I wanted to find out the size of each of the folders under `SD card`, I would run this command:

```
du -h -d1 /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host\=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD\ card/
```

This means:

- `du` is the command,
- `-h` is to show sizes in human readable format, for example MB or GB,
- `-d1` means go down only one directory (or "folder"). This means "show me the sizes of all the directories inside `SD card` only, and not the directories inside those directories. If you want to see the sizes of all the subdirectories, remove `-d1` from the command, but this will cause the command to take longer and display a lot of lines,
- `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host\=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD\ card/` is the path.

Here is how my output looks like:

```
0       /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD card/LOST.DIR
0       /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD card/TWRP
0       /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD card/.dataviz
0       /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD card/Playlists
512     /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD card/Android
5.2G    /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD card/clockworkmod
760M    /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD card/DCIM
0       /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD card/data
455M    /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD card/Music
481M    /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD card/New folder
6.9G    /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C005%5D/SD card/
```

The total size of the `SD card` folder is `6.9GB`.

I don't know how to show the total free disk space from the command line though. You can see it from the GUI: right click > Properties.

[image]

Comment: Alaa, thanks, but I am sure that mine isn't only 23 Mega
23M /run/user/1000/gvfs/gphoto2:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C004%5D/store_00020002
or 
24M /run/user/1000/gvfs/gphoto2:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C004%5D/store_00010001
after I typed:
du -h -d1 /run/user/1000/gvfs/gphoto2:host\=%5Busb%3A001%2C004%5D/store_00010001

Comment: Raj, thanks but I think it doesn't help me:
deme@PC:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 461,8G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

Comment: Hi all, is there some tool that I could install and it works similar to windows explorer? I didn't find a easy way to see the space size.

Comment: @user79885 your output shows `gphoto`, that means your phone is mounted as a "Camera (PTP)" device. This option only mounts the "camera" part of your phone, and only shows the folder containing pictures, that's why it's pretty small. On my phone (Galaxy Note 2), there are *USB Connectivity Options* that allow me to mount it as a "Media device (MTP)" or "Camera (PTP)". Check if your phone has the same options, and choose MTP instead.