# How to open the terminal from a folder by function key press?

Tags: command-line

As the title says I want to open the terminal from the folder itself.

For ex:- If I am in folder "A" and I press f12(function key 12) the terminal should open up IN the folder "A".

Comment: What file manager do you use? If default (Nautilus), then: Possible duplicate:
http://askubuntu.com/a/17963/ 
Install nautilus-open-terminal and use right-click.

Comment: found my answer http://askubuntu.com/a/72222/422234